# Two DbSet's from one BaseDbModel LINQ query issue

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

to make things short and simple here is my base dbModel (for purposes of readability I scaled models down to make them as simple as possible for this question):

```
public class BaseDbModel<T> : BaseDbModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Column(nameof(Metadata), TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public T Metadata { get; set; }
    }

public class BaseDbModel
    {
        [Column(nameof(Id))]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Column(nameof(Type))]
        public ModelTypeEnum Type { get; set; }

        [Column(nameof(Name))]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

public enum ModelTypeEnum
    {
        Coffee = 1,
        Tea = 2
    }
```

Then I set up DbSet's like this:

```
public DbSet<CoffeeDbModel> Coffees{ get; set; }
public DbSet<TeaDbModel> Teas { get; set; }
```

I also did this, so that EF Core uses only one table for multiple versions of `BaseDbModel<T>`:

```
builder.Entity<CoffeeDbModel>(x =>
            {
                x.HasKey(x => x.Id);
                x.HasIndex(x => x.Type);

                x.ToTable("Drinks");
                x.HasQueryFilter(x => x.Type == ModelTypeEnum.Coffee);
            });

            builder.Entity<TeaDbModel>(x =>
            {
                x.ToTable("Drinks");
                x.HasQueryFilter(x => x.Type == ModelTypeEnum.Tea);

                x.HasOne<CoffeeDbModel>()
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey<CoffeeDbModel>(x => x.Id);
            });
```

DbModel's for `CoffeeDbModel` and `TeaDbModel` have different fields, but are stored in column `Metadata` in `BaseDbModel`, which is saved as JSON in the db (postgre).

Basically my goal is to have multiple "versions" of entity in one table.

I tested add, edit, delete and all work fine. Metadata field get's populated correctly, type get's set correctly and when retrieving data from Coffees for example only coffees show up.

For purposes of demonstration let's say that List is a field inside a CoffeeMachineModel.

My issue is if I do any query using LINQ inside the "Metadata" field I get this exception (only when going through third model; example CoffeeMachineDbModel):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression .(redacted part here). could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

Query does have ".ToList()" at the end + if I remove the `builder.Entity<TeaDbModel>()` part from code, exception is not thrown and app works normally.

Query example that throws exception:

```
var data = _context.CoffeeMachines
    .Where(x => x.Coffees.Any(y => y.Brand == "brandName")
    .ToList();
```

If I do exact query like this (without through CoffeeMachines) it doesn't fail:

```
var data = _context.Coffees
    .Where(x => x.Brand == "brandName")
    .ToList();
```

What am I missing here?

I hope I provided enough of information on my issue and I hope there is a solution to this. Thank you for your help in advance.

****Coffee and Tea are fictional examples, since code I am working is not for public.***

I tried many different model builder configurations, suggested by others on internet and ChatGPT, but based on my Google search noone was in a similar coding situation as this, therefore I'm asking here.

Model examples:

```
public class CoffeeDbModel : BaseDbModel<CoffeeDbModel>
{
    public string Brand{ get; set; }
    public string BeanOrigin{ get; set; }
}

public class TeaDbModel: BaseDbModel<CoffeeDbModel>
{
    public string Brand{ get; set; }
    public string HerbsOrigin{ get; set; }
    public bool HasCaffeine{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share `CoffeeDbModel` and `TeaDbModel`?

Comment: Added model examples at the bottom.